# how i convert csv using pandas with a lot of delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset, delimiter

My dataset (national income):

[image: dataset national income]

How can I find what delimiter is for my dataset, because I try to read my dataset csv file using pandas libraries but I already try a comma (,), a semicolon (;), a tab (\t), a space ( ) and a pipe (|) but it still didn't work. I also try `df=pd.read_csv("file name", sep='delimiter')` but it still didn't work. Is there someone help me, what should I do?

Comment: have a look at the `skiprows` argument in `pd.read_csv`. you want to start at row 4 with `','` as delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove the first four rows of the dataset as they aren't relevant and save the CSV then everything will work fine in pandas after using `,` as delimiter OR use `skiprows` as while reading the CSV:

```
df = pd.read_csv("net_national_income.csv", skiprows = 4)
```